# How to specify Spring config path

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a maven built project built into a jar file. It is a standalone java application.

Now I tried to run this project using:

```
java -cp SpringMavenProject-1.0.jar;<maven repo path>\spring\2.5.5\spring-2.5.5.jar;
<maven repo path>\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 
com.vaannila.HelloWorldApp
```

However, it cannot find the the Spring XML config file.

I can see the config file is in the jar file created by maven.

How can I specify the path of the Spring XML file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you have the Spring context XML in a directory that's in the CLASSPATH and your app is accessing it using the `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext` (not certain of the exact class name).

If the directory that your context XML resides is not in your -cp list, I'd suggest that you add it and see if that works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should add spring-context.jar and spring-beans.jar, because they are responsible of parsing the beans configuration file.

Comment: I believe that versions of Spring earlier than 3 had everything in one JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Just **hint** - if you run maven with '-X' flag (debug) you will see all the classpath it use. So you can use this classpath by copy+paste in your standalone app.